# Issue with Mysql View and/or different method?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sphinx

I'm trying to make a mysql view to then be used with Sphinx search.

I have three tables: recipes, tags, ingredients.

**Bold Words are the row names*

Recipes is where I store the recipe **name**, and the cooking time (**durationtotal**)

Ingredients is where I store 1 ingredient needed for the specific recipe (which means there is more than 1 ingredient corresponding to every recipe.) Ingredients has a **recipe_id** which corresponds to a recipe, and **ingredient** field where I store the name of the ingredient.

Tags is similar to Ingredients, in that for every recipe, there can be more than 1 tag. For example: *Mom's Chicken Recipe has the tags(comma-delineated): yummy,chicken,thanksgiving* Tags also has a **recipe_id** field and a **tag** field which is where I store the name of the tag.

Now, I'm implementing Sphinx Search and need a way to combine the

- Recipe Id (**recipes.id**)
- Recipe Name (**recipes.name**)
- Ingredients Id (**ingredients.id**)
- Ingredients Name (**ingredients.ingredient**)
- Ingredients Corresponding Recipe Id (**ingredients.recipe_id**)
- Tags Id (**tags.id**)
- Tags Name (**tags.tag**)
- Tags Corresponding Recipe Id (**tags.recipe_id**)

My thought process (I'm a pretty programmer, and just discovered Sphinx) is to create a MYSQL view that combines all of the above rows so I'd have a view that looked like this:

> 1. RecipeName: To' Good Chicken Soup......Tag:Yummy......Ingredient:Chicken
> 2. RecipeName: To' Good Chicken Soup......Tag:Delicious......Ingredient:Chicken
> 3. RecipeName: To' Good Chicken Soup......Tag:Soup......Ingredient:Chicken
> 4. RecipeName: To' Good Chicken Soup......Tag:Yummy......Ingredient:Water

The problem with this method is, as you can see, that it duplicates a lot of rows. But since this was only the method I could think of, I went ahead and created a new view with this:

```
SELECT
   recipes.id,
   recipes.name,
   ingredients.ingredient,
   tags.tag
FROM
   recipes, ingredients, tags
WHERE
   recipes.id=ingredients.recipe_id 
AND recipes.id=tags.recipe_id;
```

I worked this code into mysql, but am only getting recipes which have tags/ingredients corresponding to them? Also, is this the right method to structure my mysql view?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all recipes regardless if they have ingredients or tags you want to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT recipes.id, recipes.name, ingredients.ingredient, tags.tag
FROM recipes
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ingredients ON recipes.id=ingredients.recipe_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON recipes.id=tags.recipe_id;
```

Comment: Why LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of normal LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

Try a LEFT JOIN:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
SELECT
   recipes.id,
   recipes.name,
   ingredients.ingredient,
   tags.tag
FROM
   recipes
LEFT JOIN ingredients ON recipes.id=ingredients.recipe_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON recipes.id=tags.recipe_id
```